# iOS Not able to switch from one tab to another

Tags: appium-ios

I am using below code to switch from one tab to another using below code.

```
appiumDriver.switchTo().window(childWindow);

Set<String> winHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        // Loop through all handles
        for(String handle: winHandles){
            if(!handle.equals(parentHandle)){
                driver.switchTo().window(handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

To switch tabs in safari instead of window handles we need to use getContexts(), below is the code:

```
Set<String> contextView = (driver).getContextHandles();
        ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>(contextView);        
        driver.context(s.get(contextView.size()-1));
```